# Remove Windows 7 windows decorations (non-client area)

Tags: windows-7, window, themes

I would like to remove the border of the windows.

I want to have all windows without their window decorations, just the content (like using a theme without borders).

I know that then I wouldn't be able to resize any window by dragging its border, but that's fine. I just want the border to be gone.

It would be also great to remove the title bar if possible.

As a note, I'm not writing an application where I need a custom UI for its windows, but I'm opened to write any kind of program if necessary.

Any help would be appreciated.

edit: all newly created windows should start without titlebar and borders.

Comment: I did not clarify it initially, but I would need that also all new windows must be created without the titlebar and borders, too, and the possible duplicate does not cover this.